# SQL Query output in VBA is different than in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, excel, recordset

Having a problem with VBA. I have written sql code (300 lines) which works perfect in SQL giving output:

```
 Line   Number     Date    Employee    PN       Tax
  1     1111   2015-10-15      AP     6225-6    L1
  2     1111   2015-10-15      AP     6225-6    L2
  3     1111   2015-10-15    (null)   CHARGE    (null)
  4     1111   2015-10-15      AP     55555     L2
```

I have inserted that big sql into my VBA code and for some reason it does not match precisely what i see in ORACLE.

What i see in VBA is this(different 3rd line):

```
 Line   Number     Date    Employee    PN       Tax
  1     1111   2015-10-15      AP     6225-6    L1
  2     1111   2015-10-15      AP     6225-6    L2
  3     1111   (null)        (null)   6225    (null)
  4     1111   2015-10-15      AP     55555     L2
```

For some reason and somehow SQL work diferently and does not give desired output in VBA. What can cause this problem??? Having no clue, as i wrote twice SQL into VBA in case thought there was my mistake.

My VBA code:

```
Sub Update_table_and_data()

'sql failo suformavimas


Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rec As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim sql As String


sql = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
"CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
"(HOST= ODB)(PORT=1525))" & _
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ABTL))); uid=ID; pwd=PWD;"

 dat1 = (Sheets("Data").Cells(2, "G"))
 dat2 = (Sheets("Data").Cells(2, "H"))

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

Sheets("Output").Range("A2:AS999999").ClearContents

If ((Not IsEmpty(dat1)) And (Not IsEmpty(dat2))) Then
  con.Open sql


    Set rec = con.Execute(" SELECT distinct ........
             ' " WHERE i.date >= to_date('" & dat1 & "','YYYY.MM.DD') 
             ' " AND i.date <= to_date('" & dat2 & "','YYYY.MM.DD' ) ) XX   order by    XX.number ")

    If Not rec.EOF Then
            Sheets("Output").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rec
            rec.Close
        Else
            MsgBox "PLEASE, CHECK DATE FORMAT!", vbCritical
        End If

    If CBool(con.State And adStateOpen) Then con.Close

    Set rec = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show your original query... this hardly looks like 300 lines of SQL code in your VBA script.

Comment: YEa... without the original SQL and the actual SQL code from VBA, there is not much we can do to help out. As it is your SQL up there makes 100% no sense and it's the most likely culprit for this problem.

Comment: Why do you need to see it?  I mean what can cause problem in it? Using  joins with simple commnads in query: distinct, case, instr,coalesce,nvl, listagg, exists..

Comment: My SQL makes sense, otherwise it wont work in Oracle

Comment: You're asking why you see different results with two queries - why wouldn't we need to see the queries to figure out what's different...?

Comment: If i copy-paste exactly same query and i do it twice so what can make a problem in it?

Comment: @orangutangas If you copy/pasted the same query, pointed to the same environment, looking at the same data, with no other changes - you would get the same result.  But you're not (hence your inquiry here), so *something* is different.  And, as you're finagling it into a VBA script, the SQL query itself is the most likely culprit.  It's extremely likely that it's not as identical as you proclaim it to be.

Comment: Do you have uncommitted changes in the session where you're running it manually? You haven't said which client you're using or how you're running it, but that's really the only reason you'd see different results, assuming you are actually connected to the same DB and schema, and really running identical code. (Different NLS settings are possible too but are more likely to cause a failure; or different timezones...). Failing that, do you have bind variables or is everything hard-coded?

Comment: @orangutangas possible check your double codes in your select statement

Comment: Edited post and included code.

Comment: So they aren't the same. Where are the `inh.invoice_date` filters in the directly-run version, for a start? Copy the VBA version back in to your client, substitute exactly the same strings for dat1 and dat2, and wee what you get.

Comment: Also, the purported query output you have shown could not possibly have come from either of the queries.

Comment: So ?? It is an extra field to have a date filter. If i incorporate same lines into SQL code and launch through Orace:  WHERE inh.invoice_date >= to_date('2015.10.15','YYYY.MM.DD') 
     and  inh.invoice_date < to_date('2015.10.16','YYYY.MM.DD')    I get same results.  Both   dat1 & dat2 are taken from another excel sheet which are values of 2015.10.15 and 2015.10.16

Comment: Not sure why you're being so antagonistic to people who are trying to help. You said the queries were identical, we're saying they are not, **as shown**. If the same query (and arguments) run against the same database and schema gets different results, then you still need to check if you have uncommitted data. You haven't answered that point.

Comment: You still need to rule out uncommitted data. Run the query from a different client to make sure you have a clean session; if you're using SQL Developer run it through SQL\*Plus, or vice versa. Then see if your client and VBA are running in the same timezone - could be an issue *if* invoice_date is a timestamp rather than a date, but seems unlikely. As mustaccio pointed out, it isn't obvious how you get from this query to the results you showed, so maybe there's another step we can't see that's causing the discrepancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `CopyFromRecordset` - it's truncating at 255 chars, and it's not the only Excel.Range method that does that.

The question is: do I have a method that doesn't? And do you have an an OLEDB driver that's doing it to your Recordset before you even get to the stage of writing to the range?

You should loop through your recordset, in VBA, and check the offending field **in VBA** for a value exceeding 255 chars in length. If the fields are truncated already, try using the native Oracle Client drivers in your connection string, instead of the Microsoft Oracle OLEDB provider - Connections.com will have the information.

Once you know that the recordset actually contains your data, without truncation, try CopyFromRecordset again. I don't actually expect it to write a field exceeding 255 chars in length, but it's been a while since I encountered the error, it might have been fixed, and it's always nice to give a pessimist a pleasant surprise.

Next up:

### A VBA Substitute for CopyFromRecordset

There are three tasks here:

1. Populate a VBA array variant with the data using
   `Recordset.GetRows()`;
2. Transpose the array, because GetRows is the wrong way 'round for
   Excel;
3. Size up a target range and write the array as
   `Range.Value = Array`, a repetitive task which
   should be automated in an ArrayToRange() routine.

...And maybe some ancillary work with writing the field  names, but I'm ignoring that in a short answer.

The end result is that you run this code:

```
    ArrayToRange rngTarget, ArrayTranspose(rst.GetRows)
```

Transposing the array is trivial, but here it is anyway:

```
Public Function ArrayTranspose(InputArray As Variant) As Variant
Application.Volatile False

Dim arrOutput As Variant

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim iMin As Long
Dim iMax As Long
Dim jMin As Long
Dim jMax As Long

iMin = LBound(InputArray, 1)
iMax = UBound(InputArray, 1)
jMin = LBound(InputArray, 2)
jMax = UBound(InputArray, 2)

ReDim arrOutput(jMin To jMax, iMin To iMax)

For i = iMin To iMax
    For j = jMin To jMax
        arrOutput(j, i) = InputArray(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

ArrayTranspose = arrOutput

End Function
```

...And ArrayToRange is trivial if you don't add checks for array dimensions and preserving formulas in the target cells: the essential point is that you can write your data in a single 'hit' if the dimensions of the range exactly match the dimensions of the array:

```
Public Sub ArrayToRange(rngTarget As Excel.Range, InputArray As Variant)
' Write an array to an Excel range in a single 'hit' to the sheet
' InputArray should be a 2-Dimensional structure of the form Variant(Rows, Columns)

' The target range is resized automatically to the dimensions of the array, with
' the top left cell used as the start point.

' This subroutine saves repetitive coding for a common VBA and Excel task.

' Author: Nigel Heffernan  http://Excellerando.blogspot.com


On Error Resume Next

Dim rngOutput As Excel.Range

Dim iRowCount   As Long
Dim iColCount   As Long

iRowCount = UBound(InputArray, 1) - LBound(InputArray, 1)
iColCount = UBound(InputArray, 2) - LBound(InputArray, 2)

With rngTarget.Worksheet

    Set rngOutput = .Range(rngTarget.Cells(1, 1), _
                           rngTarget.Cells(iRowCount + 1, iColCount + 1))

    Application.EnableEvents = False


    rngOutput.Value2 = InputArray

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Set rngTarget = rngOutput   ' resizes the range This is useful, most of the time

End With  '  rngTarget.Worksheet

End Sub
```

A note of caution: in older versions of Excel (Office 2000, if I recall) the array 'write' still truncated to 255 chars. This is no longer a problem; and if you're still using XL2000, cells containing a string exceeding 255 chars are enough of a problem that you might be glad of the truncation.

Comment: Thank you it worked!! Perfectly, just needed to create a Transpose  array and paste it to excel sheet. Thank you once again!

Comment: @Nigel Heffernan I tried he solution provided by you. But it was not useful for me. My problem seems to be bit different. When I run same query from VBA and Oracle separately, My RECORDSET values are different.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the two queries are *not* identical.

You have the following in your VBA version, but not in your Oracle version:

```
WHERE inh.invoice_date >= to_date('" & dat1 & "','YYYY.MM.DD') 
AND inh.invoice_date <= to_date('" & dat2 & "','YYYY.MM.DD' ) ) XX
```

There may be other differences as well, but that jumped out to me immediately.

Comment: So ?? It is an extra field to have a date filter. If i incorporate same lines into SQL code and launch through Orace:  WHERE inh.invoice_date >= to_date('2015.10.15','YYYY.MM.DD') 
     and  inh.invoice_date < to_date('2015.10.16','YYYY.MM.DD')    I get same results.  Both   dat1 & dat2 are taken from another excel sheet which are values of 2015.10.15 and 2015.10.16

Comment: You're clearly missing the point...  You're asking the database a different question, and confused why you're getting a different answer.  I don't have the time to go through the rest of your query, but it's possible that wasn't the only difference.

Comment: I made same query 1:1 exactly and still getting this error. If you are not familiar with that problem please do not spam this topic

Comment: @Siyual - barring whitespace and case, it does seem to be the only difference, slightly surprisingly.

Comment: @orangutangas Spam?  You asked a question, I answered.  I hardly see that as spam.

Comment: Thank you for an answer but it does not help at all

Comment: Pretty much found an differnece but not sure how to solve it. In my excel spreadsheet i have date entry lines: dat1 = (Sheets("Data").Cells(2, "G")) dat2 = (Sheets("Data").Cells(2, "H")) which is filled with 2015.10.15 and 2015.10.16 which are fed into sql querry, but this cause problem for one output line, however same to_date in Oracle works fine. Tried even write in where place not date but number to search for, had same issue that one output line is different Wrote where number = '1111' and got same different output